# Complex query containing multiple joins is not executing right outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm writing a query with multiple joins where I want every user to show entries against all category Types. When I execute the query below only 1 record is returned because the employee `u.employee_id = "0079-P"` has only worked on 1 project but I want to get data for all the `category_types` with users workhours displayed as null for the categories he didn't work on.

```
Select u.employee_id As Employee_ID, u.user_name As UserName, COALESCE(primaryDept.ctd_name, primaryProj.ctd_name) As PrimaryDeptOrProj, region.region_name As Region, categoryType.ctd_id, categoryType.ctd_name, SUM(tsdd.workhours) 
    From users u 
    LEFT JOIN category_type_details primaryDept ON u.user_primary_department = primaryDept.ctd_id
    LEFT JOIN category_type_details primaryProj ON u.user_primary_project = primaryProj.ctd_id
    LEFT JOIN regions region ON u.region_id = region.region_id
    LEFT JOIN timesheets ts ON u.user_id = ts.timesheet_user
    INNER JOIN timesheet_mr tsmr ON ts.timesheet_caller = tsmr.tsmr_id
    INNER JOIN timesheet_details tsd ON ts.timesheet_id = tsd.tsd_timesheet_id
    INNER JOIN timesheet_day_details tsdd ON tsd.tsd_id = tsdd.tsd_id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN category_type_details categoryType ON tsd.tsd_category_type_id = categoryType.ctd_id
    WHERE tsmr.tsmr_id = 14 and u.employee_id = "0079-P"
    GROUP BY u.user_id, tsd.tsd_category_type_id;
```

I tried this query with variations and it returns 1 record in any case.

Comment: Could you show your current output, your expected output, and add some sample data?

Comment: Please only tag the relevant database.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your query to this:

```
SELECT u.employee_id AS Employee_ID, u.user_name AS UserName, 
    COALESCE(pd.ctd_name, pp.ctd_name) AS PrimaryDeptOrProj, 
    r.region_name AS Region, ct.ctd_id, ct.ctd_name, SUM(tsdd.workhours) 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN category_type_details pd ON u.user_primary_department = pd.ctd_id
LEFT JOIN category_type_details pp ON u.user_primary_project = pp.ctd_id
LEFT JOIN regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id
LEFT JOIN timesheets ts ON u.user_id = ts.timesheet_user
INNER JOIN timesheet_mr tsmr ON ts.timesheet_caller = tsmr.tsmr_id AND tsmr.tsmr_id = 14
INNER JOIN timesheet_details tsd ON ts.timesheet_id = tsd.tsd_timesheet_id
INNER JOIN timesheet_day_details tsdd ON tsd.tsd_id = tsdd.tsd_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN category_type_details ct ON tsd.tsd_category_type_id = ct.ctd_id AND u.employee_id = "0079-P"
GROUP BY ct.ctd_id, u.user_id, u.employee_id, u.user_name, 
    COALESCE(pd.ctd_name, pp.ctd_name), r.region_name, ct.ctd_name
ORDER BY ct.ctd_id, u.user_id, u.employee_id, u.user_name, 
    COALESCE(pd.ctd_name, pp.ctd_name), r.region_name, ct.ctd_name;
```

You only got 1 row because the condition in `WHERE` clause filter all the `NULL` user_id rows for other category.

For `MySQL`, you could omit other columns in `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT u.employee_id AS Employee_ID, u.user_name AS UserName, 
    COALESCE(pd.ctd_name, pp.ctd_name) AS PrimaryDeptOrProj, 
    r.region_name AS Region, ct.ctd_id, ct.ctd_name, SUM(tsdd.workhours) 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN category_type_details pd ON u.user_primary_department = pd.ctd_id
LEFT JOIN category_type_details pp ON u.user_primary_project = pp.ctd_id
LEFT JOIN regions r ON u.region_id = r.region_id
LEFT JOIN timesheets ts ON u.user_id = ts.timesheet_user
INNER JOIN timesheet_mr tsmr ON ts.timesheet_caller = tsmr.tsmr_id AND tsmr.tsmr_id = 14
INNER JOIN timesheet_details tsd ON ts.timesheet_id = tsd.tsd_timesheet_id
INNER JOIN timesheet_day_details tsdd ON tsd.tsd_id = tsdd.tsd_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN category_type_details ct ON tsd.tsd_category_type_id = ct.ctd_id AND u.employee_id = "0079-P"
GROUP BY ct.ctd_id, u.user_id
ORDER BY ct.ctd_id, u.user_id;
```

Comment: Ok so this showed me only 1 more record row (with rest of the values in row as null) which means It worked perfectly in terms of display but only showed 1 more record I want it to display all 50 reports in that exact way

Comment: it worked thanks a lot. If you don't mind briefly explaining why you did what you did it would be very helpful for a newbie like me. Once again Thank you

Comment: @Saad As reason in my answer, `You only got 1 row because the condition in WHERE clause filter all the NULL user_id rows for other category.`. So I can either move the condition from `WHERE` to `ON` clause (as in my answer), or nested condition to table when join like `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM timesheet_mr WHERE tsmr_id = 14) ON...`. And because you want the category to be base table, so it should be `GROUP BY ct.ctd_id` because `tsd.tsd_category_type_id` may be null instead of the category id list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it all makes sense now